# How do I create multiple radial pie graphs on a single SVG using D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

I am currently trying to recreate a radial bracket for the 2023 NHL playoffs, the final design would look something like this [NHL Radial Bracket](https://i.redd.it/av959oipl6591.jpg).

I currently have the outermost ring completed for this but am unsure and currently unable to figure out a way to implement more radial rings past the first one I've made.

The code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
   <head>
      <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>      
      <style>
        .wedge:hover {
          stroke-width: 15;
        }
      </style>
   </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            //creating the size of SVG area
            var svg = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", 1200)
                        .attr("height", 800)
                        .style("border", "1px solid black");
            
            //moving svg area to center of page
            d3.select("svg")
              .append("g")
              .attr("transform", "translate(500,350)");
                
                //creating segments for the annulus/pie graph
                var playoffRoundOne = d3.pie()
                .startAngle(Math.PI / 4)
                .endAngle(Math.PI * 3)
                .padAngle(.03)
                .value((d) => d.wins)
                .sort(function (a, b) {
                    return b.value > a.value;
                });

                //dataset for playoff team, includes team name, team wins, and team logo
                var data = playoffRoundOne([{...}]);

                var colorScaleFill = d3.scaleOrdinal()
                                    .domain(["avalanche", "kraken", "stars", "wild", "knights", 
                                             "jets", "oilers", "kings", "bruins", "panthers", 
                                             "leafs", "lightning", "canes", "islanders", "devils", 
                                             "rangers",])
                                    .range(["#6F263D", "#99D9D9", "#006847", "#154734", "#B4975A", 
                                            "#041E42", "#FF4C00", "#A2AAAD", "#FFB81C", "#B9975B", 
                                            "#00205B", "#FFFFFF", "#CE1126", "#F47D30", "#CE1126", "#0038A8"]);
                
                //creating circles
                var arcGen = d3.arc()
                               .innerRadius(242)
                               .outerRadius(300);

                            //colors
                            d3.select("svg g")
                              .selectAll("path")
                              .data(data)
                              .enter()
                              .append("path")
                              .attr("d", arcGen)
                              .attr("stroke", (d) => colorScaleFill((d)))
                              .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
                              .attr("stroke-width", 3)
                              .attr("fill", (d) => colorScaleFill((d)))
                              .attr("class","wedge");

                                 
                  //logos
                  var imgs = svg.selectAll("image").data(data);
                            imgs.enter()
                                .append("image")
                                .attr("xlink:href", (d)=>(d.data.logo))
                                .attr("width", "30")
                                .attr("height", "40")
                                .attr("x", d => d3.pointRadial((d.startAngle + d.endAngle  - 0.02)/2 , (270))[0])
                                .attr("y", d => d3.pointRadial((d.startAngle + d.endAngle  - 0.02)/2 , (540)/2)[1])
                                .attr("transform","translate(488,330) rotate(1.2)");
  
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey @Jorge, replicating the NHL chart above is fairly involved, but here's a rough setup for this sort of visual: https://gist.github.com/AntonOrlov/6b42d8676943cc933f48a43a7c7e5b6c

Comment: I was able to find this: http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/154/
But it is using d3.v3 instead of d3.v7 does anyone know of an updated version of this? As this is exactly what I am looking for

Comment: your link isn't working